# Conditional probability in PHP

Tags: php, probability

I want to draw random numbers between 1 and 100 in PHP. I want even numbers to be drawn with a probability of 20%, odd numbers with a probability of 80%.

How can I implement this?

Comment: @BenM Perhaps it's not uniform, but it's definitively random.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function wtf_random() {
  $ret = 2 * rand(1, 50);
  if (rand(1, 5) !== 1) {
    --$ret;  
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Comment: `return 2 * rand(1, 50) - rand(1, 5) === 1` ;-)

Comment: @zerkms god bless weak typing

Comment: @zerkms - Not bad, but I'm sure it can be enhanced to be even less readable ;-P

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: not sure which is better - less maintainable (error prone) or less readable ;-)

Comment: @zerkms That is nice. Where is this documented?

Comment: @what: uhm? Where documented what?

Comment: @zerkms I actually just realized it should be `!==` :P